# Not pulling any data from JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $body = $('body');

var index = streams.home.length - 1;
while(index >= 0){
  var tweet = streams.home[index];
  var $tweet = $('<div class = tweet></div>');
  var $user = $('<div class = users></div>');
  var $message = $('<div class = message></div>');
  var $time = $('<div class = time></div>');
  // $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + ' ' + tweet.created_at);
  $tweet.appendTo($('.tweets'));
  $time.text(tweet.created_at + '\n').appendTo($tweet);
  $user.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ').attr('username', tweet.user).appendTo($tweet);
  $message.text(tweet.message + ' ').appendTo($tweet);
  index -= 1;
}

//see user history by clicking on name
  //click event on name element
  //hide all other users that do not have the same username attribute?
$('.tweets').on('click', '.users', () => {
  var user = $(this).data('users');
  console.log(user);
})
```

So I'm trying to pull data from a class when I click on it. This involves the last few lines of my code. The data stored in my `.users` should give me an output of `{someName: 'stringOfName"}` however when I click on it I get an empty object `{}`. What am I doing wrong? I'm adding data to my `.users` and I can clearly see it being displayed holding information so am I pulling the data from this object incorrectly?

Comment: `$(this).data('users');` would get info from a data-attribute called "users" on the clicked element. But I don't see anywhere in you code where you attach any data-attributes to any of your elements.

Comment: Aren't I adding a data-attribute in this line of code? `$user.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ').attr('username', tweet.user)`

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('username')`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I have tried that already. That comes out as undefined

Comment: Use a normal `function` instead of arrow function `() => {}`

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis _"Aren't I adding a data-attribute in this line of code"_ ... no. That's an attribute. But it's not a **data** attribute (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes and https://api.jquery.com/data/). It also has a different name than what you're searching for in your later code! There's also another problem. I wrote a full answer below, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).data('users');` would get info from a data-attribute called "users" on the clicked element. But I don't see anywhere in you code where you attach any data-attributes to any of your elements. You've added a "username" attribute, but that's not the same as a data-attribute, and it also has a different name.

Secondly, you can't use an arrow function as your "click" callback function because `this` will have the wrong scope. (You can read more about this [elsewhere online](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/)).

Here's a working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //some dummy data
  var streams = {
    "home": [{
      "user": "a",
      "message": "hello",
      "created_at": "Friday"
    }]
  };
  
  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while (index >= 0) {
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
    var $user = $('<div class="users"></div>');
    var $message = $('<div class="message"></div>');
    var $time = $('<div class="time"></div>');
    // $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + ' ' + tweet.created_at);
    $tweet.appendTo($('.tweets'));
    $time.text(tweet.created_at + '\n').appendTo($tweet);
    
    //create a data-attribute instead of an attribute
    $user.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ').data('username', tweet.user).appendTo($tweet);
    $message.text(tweet.message + ' ').appendTo($tweet);
    index -= 1;
  }

  //use a regular function insted of an arrow function
  $('.tweets').on('click', '.users', function() {
    var user = $(this).data('username'); //search for the correct data-attribute name
    console.log(user);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tweets"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I just changed data to attribute in the click event for my purposes. I'll need to look into the scope for this. I wasn't aware using arrow syntax for function declaration for a click event results in a different scope than using a regular function declaration